# how to develop jsp via jboss on debian as user

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jboss, debian

I would like to execute a helloWorld.jsp on a JBoss Server.

The box is an appliance. Hence, I'm not allowed to install any additional software or applications.

I found several how-to's that all look very similar, 
e.g. http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/14912.html#6.0

However, my box is missing the %JAVA_HOME/bin/jar executable.

Do you know, where I get the jar from or what would be a good workaround?

Comment: Are you just wanting to create jar or war file or do you have an application that needs to run the jar executable?

Comment: By "execute" you mean you want your JSP to be rendered by your JBoss server, so it's accessible from a browser? How is jar utility going to help you?

Comment: Or just create a .war directory to the root-dir of the tomcat server and drop all jsp there. This will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to create the jar or war file you can you use the jar executable on another machine (PC,Linux, Mac, whatever) and then copy the resulting files to the JBoss server either with scp, ftp whatever.